# I can be found in a lot of places!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I can be found in a lot of places! (but If I'm there its bad most of the time)
You might find me in different materials.

If you remove my first letter, you'll find me useful to your interior.
I can be used to sort or display.

Going on, if you remove my last letter and reverse me you may even be right in front of me.
And I wouldn't be surprised if a lot of people have used me not too long ago.

What am I?

(since this is my first riddle and I just came up with it on the fly, dont be to harsh on me please ;) .. feel free to suggest edits if its unclear or if I could reword something to make it more clear)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is

> crack

I can be found in a lot of places! (but If I'm there its bad most of the time)
You might find me in different materials.

> cracks can be seen everywhere. Often you don't want to see cracks. They can occur in wood, stone, metal, etc.

If you remove my first letter, you'll find me useful to your interior.
I can be used to sort or display.

> rack; display rack

Going on, if you remove my last letter and reverse me you may even be right in front of me.
And I wouldn't be surprised if a lot of people have used me not too long ago.

> car. I don't have one, and the last time I used one is a few days ago, but it probably is true for other people

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for! I hope I didn't give it away with the edit I made in the brackets in the first line ;)

Comment: @Radhato for me the key was in the second line :)

Answer (score 6):

Are you a ...

> stool?

I can be found in a lot of places!
You might find me in different materials all around you.

> I can see at least 14 of them right now. They are metal and cloth, but outside are wooden ones.

If you remove my first letter, you'll find me useful to your in interior.
I can be used to sort or display.

> a tool is quite useful

Going on, if you remove my last letter and reverse me you may even be right in front of me.
And I wouldn't be surprised if a lot of people have used me not too long ago.

> I haven't used the loo for a while, but now I will go there.

Comment: Good attempt, but not what I was looking for (I edited the first clue which might help)